# Android Button.setClickOnListener explanation

Tags: java, android

I saw the following code for adding a listener to a button in Android from Android's documentation:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);

         setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

         final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
         });
     }
 }
```

Well, since setOnClickListener is an Interface, we can modify the code as:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);

         setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

         final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(this);

     public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
 }
```

Well, the second code looks more logical to me, because we give to `setOnClickListener()` method argument `this`, which represents the same instance of `MyActivity` class to which the listener is attached to.

So, I don't understand how the first code works. From what I understand when we do `new Interface`, we create anonymous class which implements `Interface`. But then how the listener is attached to `MyActivity` object instead of the anonymous one since we give anonymous instance as a parameter to the listener?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, but if you create the onClickListener as an anonymous inner class, it is not attached to the Activity, but to the button itself.

Answer (score 2):

> But then how the listener is attached to MyActivity object instead of
>   the anonymous one since we give anonymous instance as a parameter to
>   the listener?

The Listener is never attached to the activity. There is not real difference between the two. In both cases you are providing an object that implements that interface. The View, will call the onClick method of the object you provided through the setter

Comment: Sidenote: inside the first example, you still have access to `this` using `MyActivity.this`.

Comment: @shkschneider depends. The `this` refers to *this object*. If the object, who `this` refers, implements the onClickListener, there is no need to make it explicitly. Imo, in this case it is just a matter of taste

Comment: @Blackbelt: Well, does this mean that the first code is creating a new object for the listener and hence it is using more memory for this object, so the second code is better because we use the same MyActivity object?

Comment: yes you are creating an additional object in the first case, but the amount of memory is negligible. I can't say if the first approach depends is better or not of the second. That depends on multiple factors.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, you're are providing an implementation of the OnClickListener Interface. Just in two different ways (they do have their subtle differences though).

I think you're getting confused with the use of the 'this' keyword, which could give the impression that the interface is attached to the class (or activity in this case) in some way (as in your second example).

When a class implements an interface you can use the 'this' keyword to refer to that implementation of the interface. Since the setOnClickListener() method is looking for a OnClickListener and not an Activity, the compiler knows that 'this' refers to the implementation of the interface that the class implements.

That does sound a little confusing reading back... but hopefully it clears it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you call  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()... a new anonymous View.OnClickListener is created and attached to the button as a callback.

When you implement View.OnClickListener your class (Activity) becomes the implementer of the interface method. In other words your class takes the role of a View.OnClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

the first way is called **anonymous inner class**, the second is ur activity class **implements** the `onClickListener` interface, and a 3rd way could be a **separated class** that implements the onClickListener interface,and u pass instance of that class to setOnClickListener() but this could be harder, as you may need to interact with objects in the activity class, as said , all will work, it's just techniques and u can choose based on ur needs.